# Is there a reasonable way to implement a cd command on VMS?

Tags: vms

I would like to be able to say things like

**cd [.fred]** and have my default directory go there, 
and my prompt change to indicate the full path to my current location.

Comment: Voting you up just for having the only (first) vms-tagged question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my setup:

You need 2 files (typed below) : godir.com and prompt.com in your sys$login

You may define a symbole

```
CD == "@sys$login:godir.com"
```

But I suggest you to use something else... (ie SD == "@sys$login:godir.com")

I modify the help text. It was in french...

You will have to retype the escape caracters into godir.com 
Replace ESC by the real escape into GRAPH_BOUCLE: (see bottom of godir.com)

Then to use it:

```
SD ?
SD a_directory
...
```

Hope it helps.

---

Here's prompt.com

```
$       noeud   = f$trnlnm("SYS$NODE") - "::"
$       if noeud .eqs. "HQSVYC" then noeud = "¥"
$!
$       noeud = noeud - "MQO"
$       def_dir = f$directory()
$       def_dir = f$extract(1,f$length(def_dir)-2,def_dir)
$boucle:
$       i = f$locate(".",def_dir)
$       if i .eq. f$length(def_dir) then goto fin_boucle
$       def_dir = f$extract(i+1,f$length(def_dir)-1,def_dir)
$       goto boucle
$!
$fin_boucle:
$!      temp = "''noeud' ''def_dir' " + "''car_prompt'"
$       temp = "''noeud'" -
             + " ''def_dir' " -
             + "''f$logical(""environnement"")'" -
             + "''car_prompt'"
$!      temp = "''noeud'" -
$!           + "''def_dir'" -
$!           + "''f$logical(""environnement"")'" -
$!           + "''car_prompt'"
$       set prompt="''temp' "
$!
$! PROMPT.COM
$!
```

Here's godir.com

```
$!
$! GODIR.COM
$!
$       set noon
$       set_prompt = "@sys$login:prompt.com"
$       if f$type(TAB_DIR_N) .nes. "" then goto 10$
$       goto 20$
$ INIT:
$       temp2 = "INIT"
$ CLEAR:
$       temp = 0
$
$ INIT2:
$       temp = temp +1
$       if temp .gt. TAB_DIR_N then goto INIT3
$       delete/symb/glo TAB_DIR_'temp'
$       goto INIT2
$
$ INIT3:
$       P1 = ""
$       if temp2 .eqs. "INIT" then goto 20$
$       delete/symb/glo TAB_DIR_N
$       delete/symb/glo TAB_DIR_P
$       delete/symb/glo TAB_DIR_I
$       exit
$
$ 20$:
$       TAB_DIR_N == 1
$       TAB_DIR_P == 1
$       TAB_DIR_I == 1
$       if "''car_prompt'" .eqs. "" then car_prompt == ">"
$       TAB_DIR_1 == f$parse(f$dir(),,,"device")+f$dir()
$ 10$:
$       if P1 .eqs. ""  then goto LIST
$       if P1 .eqs. "?" then goto SHOW
$       if P1 .eqs. "." then P1 = "[]"
$       if P1 .eqs. "^" then goto SET_CUR
$       if (P1 .eqs. "<") .or. (P1 .eqs. ">") .or. -
           (P1 .eqs. "..") then P1 = "[-]"
$       if (P1 .eqs. "*") .or. (P1 .eqs. "0") then goto HOME
$       if (P1 .eqs. "P") .or. (P1 .eqs. "p") then goto PREVIOUS
$       if (P1 .eqs. "H") .or. (P1 .eqs. "h") then goto HELP
$       if (P1 .eqs. "S") .or. (P1 .eqs. "s") then goto SET_PROMPT
$       if (P1 .eqs. "G") .or. (P1 .eqs. "g") then goto SET_PROMPT_GRAPHIC
$       temp2 = ""
$       if (P1 .eqs. "~INIT")  .or. (P1 .eqs. "~init")  then goto INIT
$       if (P1 .eqs. "~CLEAR") .or. (P1 .eqs. "~clear") then goto CLEAR
$
$!      *** Specification par un numero
$       temp = f$extract(0,1,P1)
$       if temp .eqs. "-" then goto DELETE
$       temp2 = ""
$boucle_reculer:
$       if temp .nes. "\" then goto fin_reculer
$       temp2 = temp2 + "-."
$       P1 = P1 - "\"
$       temp = f$extract(0,1,P1)
$       goto boucle_reculer
$!
$fin_reculer:
$       P1 = temp2 + P1
$       if (P1 .lts. "0") .or. (P1 .gts. "9") then goto SPEC
$       temp = f$integer("''P1'")
$       if temp .eq. 0 then goto HOME
$       if (temp .lt. 1) .or. (temp .gt. TAB_DIR_N) then goto ERR
$       TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_I
$       TAB_DIR_I == temp
$       goto SET2
$
$ SPEC:
$!      *** Specification relative de directory
$
$       temp = f$parse("[.''P1']","missing.mis")
$       DD = f$extract(0,f$locate("]",temp)+1,temp)
$       if DD .nes. "" then goto SET1
$
$!      *** Specification de directory principal
$
$       temp = f$parse("[''P1']","missing.mis")
$       DD = f$extract(0,f$locate("]",temp)+1,temp)
$       if DD .nes. "" then goto SET1
$
$       temp = f$parse("[''P1']","sys$login:missing.mis")
$       DD = f$extract(0,f$locate("]",temp)+1,temp)
$       if DD .nes. "" then goto SET1
$
$!      *** Specification exacte de directory
$
$       temp = f$parse(P1,"missing.mis")
$       if f$locate("]"+P1,temp) .ne. f$length(temp) then goto ERR
$       if f$locate(".][",temp) .ne. f$length(temp) then temp = temp - "]["
$       DD = f$extract(0,f$locate("]",temp)+1,temp)
$!      if DD .eqs. TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I' then goto SHOW
$       if DD .eqs. TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I' then goto SET2
$       if DD .nes. "" then goto SET1
$
$       temp = f$parse(P1,"sys$login:missing.mis")
$       if f$locate("]"+P1,temp) .ne. f$length(temp) then goto ERR
$       if f$locate(".][",temp) .ne. f$length(temp) then temp = temp - "]["
$       DD = f$extract(0,f$locate("]",temp)+1,temp)
$!      if DD .eqs. TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I' then goto SHOW
$       if DD .eqs. TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I' then goto SET2
$       if DD .nes. "" then goto SET1
$
$       goto ERR
$
$ HOME:
$       DD = "SYS$LOGIN"
$
$ SET1:
$       Set On
$       On error then goto ERR1
$       set message/nofac/noid/nosever/notext
$       Set def 'DD'
$       dir/output=nl:
$       set message/fac/id/sever/text
$       temp = f$parse(f$dir()) - ".;"
$       if temp .nes. "" then goto SET1F
$ ERR1:
$       set message/fac/id/sever/text
$       temp = TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I'
$       Set def 'temp'
$       goto ERR
$ SET1F:
$       I = 0
$ LOOP1:
$       I = I + 1
$       if temp .eqs. TAB_DIR_'I' then goto FOUND
$       if I .lt. TAB_DIR_N then goto LOOP1
$
$       TAB_DIR_N == TAB_DIR_N + 1
$       TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_I
$       TAB_DIR_I == TAB_DIR_N
$       TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I' == temp
$       goto SHOW
$
$ FOUND:
$       TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_I
$       TAB_DIR_I == I
$       goto SET2
$
$ SET_PROMPT:
$       car_prompt == "''P2'"
$       set_prompt
$       exit
$
$ PREVIOUS:
$       temp = TAB_DIR_P
$       TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_I
$       TAB_DIR_I == temp
$
$ SET_CUR:
$ SET2:
$       DD = TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I'
$       set def 'DD'
$
$ SHOW:
$       temp = TAB_DIR_'TAB_DIR_I'
$       ws "  ''TAB_DIR_I' * ''temp'"
$       set_prompt
$       exit
$
$ LIST:
$       I = 0
$ LOOP2:
$       I = I + 1
$       temp = TAB_DIR_'I'
$       if I .eq. TAB_DIR_I then goto L_CUR
$       if I .eq. TAB_DIR_P then GOTO L_PRE
$       ws "  ''I' = ''temp'"
$       goto F_LOOP2
$ L_CUR:
$       ws "  ''I' * ''temp'"
$       goto F_LOOP2
$ L_PRE:
$       ws "  ''I' + ''temp'"
$
$ F_LOOP2:
$       if I .lt. TAB_DIR_N then goto LOOP2
$       set_prompt
$
$       exit
$
$ DELETE:
$       P1 = P1 - "-"
$       temp2 = f$integer("''P1'")
$ DEL_1:
$       temp = f$integer("''P1'")
$       if (temp .lt. 1) .or. (temp .gt. TAB_DIR_N) then goto ERR
$       if temp .eq. TAB_DIR_I then goto ERR
$       if temp .lt. TAB_DIR_I then TAB_DIR_I == TAB_DIR_I - 1
$       if temp .eq. TAB_DIR_P then TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_I
$       if temp .lt. TAB_DIR_P then TAB_DIR_P == TAB_DIR_P - 1
$ LOOP3:
$       if temp .eq. TAB_DIR_N then goto F_LOOP3
$       temp3 = temp + 1
$       TAB_DIR_'temp' == TAB_DIR_'temp3'
$       temp = temp + 1
$       goto LOOP3
$ F_LOOP3:
$       delete/symb/glo tab_dir_'tab_dir_n'
$       TAB_DIR_N == TAB_DIR_N - 1
$       if P2 .eqs. "" then goto FIN_DEL
$       temp2 = temp2 + 1
$       if temp2 .le. f$integer("''P2'") then goto DEL_1
$ FIN_DEL:
$       goto LIST
$
$ ERR:
$       ws "*** ERREUR ***"
$       exit
$
$ HELP:
$       ws "    H       Show this menu"
$       ws "    null    Show a list of directories"
$       ws "    ?       Show current directory"
$       ws "    < or [-] or"
$       ws "    > or .. Remonte d'un niveau de directory"
$       ws "    * ou 0  Return to SYS$LOGIN"
$       ws "    P       Last directory "
$       ws "    . ou [] Set cureent directory"
$       ws "    ^       Return to next directory"
$       ws "    x       Set def to number x"
$       ws "    -x      Remove the number x"
$       ws "    -x y    Remove from x to y"
$       ws "    ddd     Set def to [ddd] or [.ddd] or ddd:"
$       ws "    \ddd    Set def to [-.ddd]"
$       ws "    S "">>""  Modify prompt for >>"
$       ws "    ~INIT   Initialize to current directory "
$       ws "            (and delete all others references)"
$       ws "    ~CLEAR  Remove all references
$       ws ""
$
$       exit
$
$ SET_PROMPT_GRAPHIC:
$       temp = "''P2'"
$       i=0
$       car_prompt == ""
$ GRAPH_BOUCLE:
$       t=f$extract(i,1,temp)
$       if (t .eqs. "e") .or. (t .eqs. "E") then t="ESC"
$       if (t .eqs. "g") .or. (t .eqs. "G") then t="ESC(0"
$       V° (} .L-_. "N") .-_. (} .L-_. "H") }NL+ }="ESC(B"
$       car_prompt == car_prompt + t
$       i = i+1
$       if i .lts. f$length(temp) then goto GRAPH_BOUCLE
$
$       set_prompt
$       exit
```

Answer (score 8):

Just type

`cd:==set default`

at the command prompt. You can also put this in your LOGIN.COM file, but be sure to put a $ in front, i.e.

`$ cd:==set default`

To change your prompt to show your default, something like this may work up to a point

`$ set prompt='f$env("default")'`

There is a problem though with the fact that VMS prompt has maximum 32 characters, and your default might be longer than that. Have a look at [this page](http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=19&id=2) for a way around that problem.

Answer (score 4):

My DCL is *really* rusty, but can't you create an alias for SET DEFAULT named CD?

Answer (score 1):

Use HGSD which implements an SD (short for SET DEFAULT) command. Just google it. It is an improved version by Hunter Goatley of an older implementation.

The only thing it cannot handle (yet), are logicals with multiple translations. Other than that, It works like a charm, and you do not need to type in complete directory names. You can even move to the next directory on the same level.

It can also set the prompt if you have the right privileges in one go, so your prompt will reflect your default directory, just like in the old days on DOS.

Comment: I have discussed some improvements with Hunter, but like a lot of people, he is a busy man :)